# How to install php8.0-mbstring for php8.0? It keeps installing to php7.2

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, php

I am trying to install Laravel. I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, have php 8.0.2, and running Apache2. My issue is that I can't install Laravel as it keeps giving the error that I don't have the 'mbstring' extension.

When I do the commands

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

they get installed to /etc/php/7.2/mods-available. Laravel is looking for the extensions in /etc/php/8.0/. I have also tried installing the newest version of mbstring:

```
sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring
```

But get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-mbstring
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-mbstring'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-mbstring'
```

Can someone help me figure this out? Why does mbstring not get installed to php8.0, and why can't I install mbstring for 8.0? I have googled online and found guides for installing mbstring for 8.0 and this specific command, but I can't see that extension.

Comment: The `php8.0-mbstring` is provided from this repository : https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php

Comment: Thank you for that information. Would that mean I don't use 'apt install php8.0-mbstring'? What would I have to do instead? All the links I click on google tell me to do that same command.

Comment: It worked! I had to read that document a bit to figure out what you mean. Thanks! Posting the answer as a full comment below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to  Michal Przybylowicz's comment.

The website's repository: [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) needs to be added to Ubuntu's package system. The site lists the commands to do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

I also did:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2`

since I run apache2. After that Laravel said that I need the 'dom' extension as well. That was solved by:

`sudo apt install php8.0-dom`

After that Laravel finally installed! Thanks Michal!

Comment: I am a bit skeptical, can this repo be trusted?

Comment: Few months later, everything seems to be fine. So far I see no reason to doubt that repository.

Comment: @Teso Ondrej appears to be the official Debian package manager for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

@kush solution worked great for me - after +4 hours of trying stuff.

Obviously, also works if you get this errors:

**curl**

*PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/curl (/usr/lib/php/20200930/curl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20200930/curl.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/curl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0*

`sudo apt install php8.0-curl` or `sudo apt install php[your-version]-curl`

**mbstring**

*PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/mbstring (/usr/lib/php/20200930/mbstring: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)*

`sudo apt install php8.0-mbstring` or `sudo apt install php[your-version]-mbstring`